# AudioPlayer (Swift) - play sound twice - with gap

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer

I'm using the following code to play a sound file twice. The second sound plays immediately following the first

Is it possible to leave a time gap (1 second) between them? I've tried to find a solution reading the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer/1386071-numberofloops)

```
var letterSound: AVAudioPlayer!

...


     @IBAction func speakLetter(sender: AnyObject) {

            let soundFile: String  = "SoundFile" + String(letterNumber)

            let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: soundFile, ofType:"mp3")!
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

            do {
                let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
                letterSound = sound
                letterSound.numberOfLoops = 1
                letterSound.play()

            } catch {
                // couldn't load file :(
            }

        }
```

Comment: Could you add a 1 second 'white space' or gap at the end of the audio file? - You could also consider using the `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` [didFinishPlaying](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayerdelegate/1389160-audioplayerdidfinishplaying) method to detect the end of the first play and then play the sound again after one second delay.

Comment: I'll try these ideas, thanks

Comment: I used your first suggestion. If you write it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to add some 'white space' or silence at the end of your audio file.

[image]

If you don't have an audio editor i'd recommend [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/), it's free and there are lots of tutorials on [how to add silence.](https://youtu.be/tnts9Rzw1GM)

---

If you want a more code based option you could look in to using the `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` [didFinishPlaying](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayerdelegate/1389160-audioplayerdidfinishplaying) method to detect the end of the first play and then use `play(atTime:)` to trigger the next loop 1 second from now.

```
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    player.play(atTime: player.deviceCurrentTime + 1.0)
}
```

This code is untested and I think it might create an infinite loop so you may need some additional logic here to make sure it only loops once

Comment: I tried using code, but I could not find that method. I ended up adding white space using SoundStudio. Thanks a lot for the help.